# What are some applications of parametrization of curves and surfaces?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, surfaces, curves

I know that we can find all elements of a quadratic field with norm 1 by rational parametrization of conics, it can be used to show that some Diophantine equations are not so easy to solve, and that rational parametrization of surfaces is helpful in modelling some implicitly defined surfaces. Are there other applications of rational parametrization of curves and surfaces in number theory, coding theory, cryptography, or elsewhere?